# LDAP authentication for specific users

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I made login via LDAP, but I would like only 3 people to access the site.

They are members of different groups, and I do not want to give permission to the whole group.

How to make a `$username` comparison with specific AD usernames? I try this but not working...

```
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
    $account_suffix = 'domain';
    $hostname = 'ldap://hostname';

    $con =  ldap_connect($hostname);
    if (!is_resource($con)) trigger_error("Unable to connect to $hostname",E_USER_WARNING);
    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    if (!$username = 'specific_usersname') die("HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized: Access is denied");

    if (ldap_bind($con,$username . $account_suffix, $password)) echo 'Access granted!';
    else  echo 'Access Denied!';
```